# Which version of solidity is most stable to use?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js

Suppose I am making an NFT Marketplace project, which version of node and solidity should I use so they don't conflict with between packages?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on which packages you are going to use.

Because you did not the list of the packages in the question, then it is not possible to give a better answer.

[I also suggest to read xyproblem](https://xyproblem.info/) for asking more precise question.